# Why doesn't work Integer factorization for fields?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers

I try to unterstand, why the Integer factorization is only working for rings and not for fields. My first idea was, that you don't have a uniqueness quantification for prime "numbers" in fields. Is that correct? It would be nice if someone would explain it to me.

Greetings.

Comment: There are no prime numbers in a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no prime numbers in a field. Every non-zero element of a field is a *unit*, where a unit is defined as a number $a$ which has a multiplicative inverse. A *prime* $p$ is in general defined as an object which is neither $0$ nor a unit, and such that whenever $p$ divides $ab$, $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$. An object $p$ is *irreducible* if $p$ is neither $0$ nor a unit, and whenever $p=ab$, one of $a$ or $b$ is a unit. So by definition there are neither primes nor irreducibles in a field.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds quite clear

Answer (score 1):

Prime elements, irreducible elements etc. are defined in an arbitrary integral domain. An integral domain is called factorial (or UFD) if every non-zero non-unit is a product of prime elements. This decomposition is essentially unique. So this captures the notion of unique prime factorization in ring theory. Now it is trivial to verify that fields *are* factorial: There is non non-zero non-unit at all, so nothing has to be checked. In particular, the answer to "Why doesn't work Integer factorization for fields?" is: No, it works! The answers so far indicate that it doesn't work because of the abscence of prime elements, but this doesn't matter.